# To carpool, what do you call the passenger?

Tags: word-choice, nouns

During a carpool, the driver is called the carpooler but I can't find any words for the passengers who share the same car, how can I call them?

Comment: https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/carpooler says *carpooler* is just "a member of a carpool".

Comment: Oh my bad, so how can I distinguish the driver and the passengers ?

Comment: @Kariamoss: You wouldn't usually *want* to specifically identify one member of a carpool as "the driver" except in contexts where you're only talking about the person driving on *one specific journey*, since for most people the whole *point* of a carpool is that by default the members (who must all have cars and be available as drivers) share that role more or less equally. So there can't really be a word identifying the [one and only, *permanently* assigned] driver since there wouldn't usually be any such person.

Comment: @FumbleFingers If you take a presentation about carpool, let's say about blablacar for example, you have to differentiate both because they have a completely different approach of the service.

Comment: On a separate note, the question is phrased as *what do you call* or *how do you say*. Ask *how do you call* and some 7-year-old in the room will respond "with a telephone of course."

Comment: If *carpooler* is the driver, then a passenger is a *carpoolee* :D

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To me, and apparently to the compiler of Collins dictionary, a "[carpooler](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/carpooler)" would be a member of a carpool, whether they drive or not. Many carpools are structured so that different people drive on different days.

If a carpool has a single driver you can just say "the driver in the carpool" or "the nominated driver of the carpool".  Another phrase is "[designated driver](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/designated-driver)", which is often used when a group of people go out drinking, but one chooses to stay sober and drive the others home. Similarly you could say "passengers in the carpool" or "non-drivers of the carpool".

Comment: What about *carpool driver/passenger*?

Comment: Sure, I'd understand that.

Comment: +1 .  A *carpool* is the collective group, of whom the *driver* is the one driving on that day.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could use either of these:

- passengers
- riders

Of those two, I think *passenger* sounds more formal, and *rider* more informal.

It’s easy to find dictionary definitions supporting *passenger*, but finding one for *rider* was harder to do. I did find one on the [Wordnik](https://www.wordnik.com/words/rider) page:

> **rider** (*noun*) a traveler riding in a vehicle (a boat or bus or car or plane or train etc) who is not operating it